# jquery form validation plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery form validation to validate my form but I am getting the following errors:

```
         Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.validate.js:1178
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function bootstrap.js:29
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined mimi.html:20
```

here's my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
    <link type = "text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />

       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
       <script src="js/bootstrap.js"> </script>
       <script> 
                 $(function(){ 
                                 $('form').validate()
                             }); 
        </script> 
 </head>
 <body> 
 <form class = "well span6"> 

 <label> Username </label> 
 <input type="text" id = "myName" class ="span3" placeholder ="Type your username here..." class = "required"/> 

  <label> Password</label> 
 <input type="text" id "myPassword" class ="span3" placeholder ="Type your password here..." class = "required"/> <br/> 

 <button id = "submit" class ="btn btn-primary">Submit </button>
 <button class = "" > Clear <br/></button><br/> 
 </form> 



 </body> 

</html>
```

I would appreciate your help folks.

Comment: The error explains everything perfectly.  To use a jQuery plugin, first requires jQuery itself.  I don't see jQuery included in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[jQuery Validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) requires jQuery. You can include just before the `jquery.validate.js` script.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: o, thanks. I tried that and I also added this:  <script> 
              $('#submit').click(function(){ 
                     $('form').validate()
        }); 
    
  </script>

Comment: Now, when I click my button, how come I dont get an error message or anything?

Comment: @Stranger, your original question has been correctly answered.  Please accept it and post a new question about your new issue.  BTW- binding `.validate()` to a `click` handler is not the correct way to use the plugin.

Comment: Sounds like it's in place, then. Calling `.validate` the first time will initialize the plugin. You can supply additional options to add rules and modify the behavior for adding/clearing errors (such as adding or removing CSS selectors to indicate a field is invalid). Documentation is here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation